# Form submit is not happening in google chrome Intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-chrome

I have a webpage which contains iFrame. This webpage auto-submits a form to third party url which loads the content in iFrame. I am currently doing the auto-submit of the form on document.ready() through jQuery and it looks like chrome is not submitting this form intermittently.

Below is the sample html in my webpage.

```
<form id="form_init" target="myFrame" action="https://somethirdpartyurl.com/req.jsp?queryParam=value" method="post" class=" edit accessAid">
    <input name="_cs" id="_cs2" value="blah" type="hidden">
    <input name="cs" id="cs2" value="blah" type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="howdy" value="oneMoreBlah">
    <input type="hidden" name="myUrl" value="http://localhost:8000/myapp?_eventId=processing&amp;sessionId=123">
    <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="1234567891234567">
    <div id="submit_button">
        <p>Attention: This form can't be displayed because JavaScript is disabled in your browser.</p>
        <p class="buttons">
            <span class="buttonAsLink">
                <input type="submit" name="" class="button autoSubmit" value="Click here to continue">
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<iframe name="myFrame" id="myFrame" width="625px" height="480px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/grey_spacer.gif"></iframe>

<script src="http://www.localhost:8000/myapp/webstatic/js/loadFrame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Below is the snippet for loadFrame.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").length && ($("#submit_button").hide(), $("#submit_button input").hasClass("autoSubmit") && $("#submit_button input")[0].form.submit());
});
```

Note that all the conditions before `$("submit_button input")[0].form.submit()` command are success.I have confirmed it through console logs.

The problem I am facing now is, chrome is not submitting the above form intermittently. This issue is not present in other browsers like FireFox and Safari.

One observation is that, when I open developer tools and checking the disable cache option, most of the times form is not getting submitted. If I uncheck the option, mostly the form is getting submitted. (This is true for majority of the times, not all)

One more thing is, when I manually execute the same command `$("submit_button input")[0].form.submit()` in console, chrome is submitting the form and everything working fine.

Can someone tell me why this issue is coming or at least an alternative solution for this issue? I am hoping that all the required information is provided. Let me know, if you need any other details.

Comment: Well, `console.log()` returns `undefined` so a condition like that would never submit the form, but I'm assuming you were just testing weather conditions succeeded. Anyways, do you a see an error message in the network panel of devtools whenever the form doesnt submit?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Yeah, thats true. I added to see whether the initial conditions are causing any trouble. Even without `console.log()` I am facing the same issue. No, I am not seeing any error or warning message in network/console tab of devtools.

Comment: You know you code is broken. Look at the parens carefully. It is better if you split the code on to multiple lines.

Comment: @SalmanA I don't think the code is broken. As I mentioned, this is very intermittent scenario. This code is working from years and I got this issue recently.

Comment: Well there is a mismatching bracket, and everyone is thinking that it is the problem.

Comment: My bad. I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I didn't split my code on to multiple lines because this is how it is in my codebase and I wanted to keep it pristine

Comment: If everything is working fine in other browsers then try executing the conditions from document.ready inside a timeout function with around 500 ms timeout and see if it works. If yes, then your conditions are executing before the form is loaded in chrome.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I thought of this use case. I have done console.log of form element before auto submit to check if this is happening. It's printing the form element as expected. So, I eliminated this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `about:blank` in the iframe or do the form submit on the iframe's `onload` function.

It could be that the image load given in the `src` of the iframe is interrupting the form submit.

Comment: +1 this sounds right.. inconsistent loading of the `iframe` so it may not be ready when the parent document is `ready` - if it is cached it may work, otherwise depends on timing and is not reliable unless you do the `onload` .. use browser dev tools network info to see whether getting 304 cache hit vs 200 OK may help verify this

Answer (score 0):

try below snippet.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        if($("#submit_button").length){
            $("#submit_button").hide();
           if( $("#submit_button input").hasClass("autoSubmit")){
               $("#form_init").submit();
           }

        }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking Syed's advice by changing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").length && ($("#submit_button").hide(), $("#submit_button input").hasClass("autoSubmit") && $("#submit_button input")[0].form.submit());
});
```

to this

```
$(top.myFrame).load(function() {
    $("#submit_button").length && ($("#submit_button").hide(), $("#submit_button input").hasClass("autoSubmit") && $("#submit_button input")[0].form.submit());
});
```

not sure if that will work if the `iframe` is from different origin tho..

Comment: Problem with this approach is, if the image is failed to load here, auto submit will not happen. I want to auto submit the form irrespective of whether the iframe src is loaded or not. So, I went with about:blank approach and looks like it solved the problem.